# AES Encrpyt and Decrypty the same with object-c and java

Tags: java, android, ios

I have a server that has implentment use java.
The code is that encrpyt is:

```
private static final byte[] RAW = "icanplayWillBeth".getBytes();
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kgen.init(128);
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(RAW,"AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,skeySpec);`
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(XXXXX);
```

and the  Decrypty has no problem when Android use code to Encrpyt.
It's like that the server use AES 128bit and default use ECB , PKCS5Padding;
How can I implentment the same code on IOS,use Object-c!

Comment: Have you tried and failed or have not at all?  There are quite number of this snippets out there on SO.

Comment: I have tried,but it's failed.There are many question like this,but I can not find the right answer.My server is work,and the android app can connent with it.Somebody say that in IOS,there only PKCS7Padding,but in Java,there is no PKCS7Padding.I want to know that should I not use AES,only use DES(in some model, PKCS7Padding is the same with PKCS5Padding).Must I change the server ?Thank youl